# Stable reactid for server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs

When using React to render components on the server, I notice that the data-reactid attributes are effectively random. I understand that's expected. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/ewTN-WOP1w8)

However it's a little surprising that this otherwise functional framework introduces such non-determinism in the view output. It means that successive renderings of a view with identical state will create different HTML, preventing, for instance, the view engine from returning a '304 Not Modified' or generating a reliable ETag. (I appreciate such caching could be handled at a higher infrastructure layer as well.)

Is there a way to seed the generation of the identifier so that the reactids are deterministic? Or is the reason that's a bad idea explained somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

In the final comment on the [Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/ewTN-WOP1w8/7ogFwEEQtqwJ) Ben Alpert says:

> For server rendering, it's important that different rendered components don't have colliding IDs (even if they're rendered on different servers, for instance) so we pick them at random.

Comment: Other than saying "it's important", it's not clear why that is.

Comment: I read his comment as saying the reason React uses random IDs is because the components can't have colliding IDs, even across different servers. There's some talk of changing [how the random IDs are created on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2584) and you could  follow their lead to generate your own IDs if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Also recently thought about it(just started to use reactjs),

Possible solution is quite simple - there is no requirement for ETag to be generated from real html...  - it can be generated from displayed data.

So you can generate it from virtual dom - just use `React.renderComponentToStaticMarkup(…)` and generate ETag from it...

Or you can remove all reactid's from rendered html with regexp before hashing it(likely faster then separate render)...

In case if you are using express, this would be something like:

```
var virtualDom = React.createFactory(Handler)({});
var html = React.renderToString(virtualDom);

var etag = app.get('etag fn');
if (etag) {
  etag = etag(React.renderComponentToStaticMarkup(virtualDom), 'utf8');
  etag && res.set('ETag', etag);
}

res.render( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

This was bugging me too, so I did some digging to see what would happen if I made the root reactid deterministic.

It is possible override this in React 0.14.x if you're willing to put up with the following hack. In your server-side file where you call ReactDOM.renderToString, place this at the top:

```
// Override the ServerReactRootIndex.createReactRootIndex function
var ServerReactRootIndex = require('react/lib/ServerReactRootIndex');
ServerReactRootIndex.createReactRootIndex = function(){
    return "x"; // Results in an attribute like data-reactid=".x"
};

// Use React as usual
// NB: require('react') must come AFTER overriding ServerReactRootIndex.createReactRootIndex
var React = require('react');
```

This isn't part of the React API, so this may break in the near future. However, this works for now if you absolutely need it. It also makes the data-react-checksum attribute stable for the same rendered DOM.

If you have multiple root React components in the one page, they MUST have different root ids, so you will need to modify this function to account for this.